# How to change Foreground color of TextBlock in DataTemplate from code on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to change Foreground color of TextBlock (bellow TitleText and DateText) in DataTemplate from code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="35" x:Name="TitleText" Text="{Binding Title}" Width="386" Foreground="Black" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" x:Name="DateText" Text="{Binding Date}" Width="78" Foreground="Black" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Id" Text="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'd like to do like this in code behind. But It seems not be able to access x:Name property in DataTemplate.

```
this.TitleText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Does anyone know a good solution for this ?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480242/wp7-change-textblock-foreground-color-based-on-another-textblocks-value

Comment: Is TitleText a unique name? Why not just TitleText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: @ameer - Its in a DataTemplate! You cant use x:Name within a template from the code-behind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you do it the **Fast** way instead of crawling the Visual Tree.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="35" Text="{Binding Title}" Width="386" Foreground="[Binding Color}" />
```

Then all you have to do is:

1. Add a `Color` Brush Property in your Collection
2. Change this property to the color you want
3. Make sure this property implement INotify or is a Dependency Property

### Example

#### XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding TitleColor}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Foreground="Black" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

#### CodeBehind

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<TEST> TestCollection { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestCollection = new ObservableCollection<TEST>();
        TestCollection.Add(new TEST()
        {
            TitleColor = Brushes.Black,
            ID = 0,
            Title = "A",
            Date = DateTime.Now,
        });

        TestCollection.Add(new TEST()
        {
            TitleColor = Brushes.Red,
            ID = 1,
            Title = "B",
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        });

        DataContext = TestCollection;
    }
}

public class TEST : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Brush _TitleColor;
    public Brush TitleColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _TitleColor;
        }

        set
        {
            _TitleColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TitleColor");
        }
    }

    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }

        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _Title;
        }

        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _Date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _Date;
        }

        set
        {
            _Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    public TEST()
    {
    }

    #region INotifyProperty
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, MyKuLLSKI. I implemented your code in my app. But PropertyChanged became null everytime, so Color property were not changed. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @ShingoTada - You have a binding issue most likely. If its null then no one is using the event. Make sure your TestCollection has items in it and make sure you set there values. Copy and pasting my code directly WILL work.

Comment: Thanks. I understood my problem. I'll try to learn INotifyPropertyChanged pattern more. Anyway your code is not Windows Phone.(WPF?) So, I can't copy and paste to my app.

Comment: I found a new thing. I questioned as a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570011/how-to-change-foreground-color-of-textblock-in-datatemplate-from-code-on-windows

Comment: You should mark this as the solution, because I tested it and I directly copy/pasted it here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindItem` method to find element in visual tree by it name and then change it `Foregorund`.

```
((listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5) as FrameworkElement).FindName("TitleText") as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 128));
```

where 5 is your item index

Comment: Thanks reply. But I couldn't find FindName method. There may not be in WP Silverlight.

Comment: thanks, but still I could't find Foreground. Do I need to cast TextBlock?

Comment: ((listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5) as FrameworkElement).FindName("TitleText") as TextBlock).Foregound is not work... So, Do you know solution for this?

Comment: I tried, and it compiles for me. What error do you have? Please write this code line-by-line to get place where exactly exception is generated

Comment: thanks. code : ((listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5) as FrameworkElement).FindName("TitleText") as TextBlock) error : Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: ... = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 128)); don't forget

Comment: really thanks! I could build it. But still error... NullReferenceException. It seems not to be able to find listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1). listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) becomes Could not evaluate expression in Watch view.

Comment: do you have 2 items in List? (zero-based indexes)

Comment: No, I bind the list from database. So item's number is depend on database rows. I want to change the color of all list items. So, I think I can't use ContainerFromIndex in my code. Am I correct ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To Expand on MyKuLLSKI's answer, if your change is based on some value already in your object (eg. an int property that is greater than 5), you could use a ValueConverter ([see here for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) to read the value and return a brush.  That is cleaner than adding a colour to your model since it is (arguably) UI related rather than data related.

Answer (score -1):

MyKuLLSKI gave me perfect solution. But I couldn't make it.

I was struggling and I found my problem. I wrote the answer (only for me ) in my blog. Please take a glance it.

Cannot bind two types of data source to one UI target
http://myprogrammingdial.blogspot.com/2012/03/cannot-bind-two-types-of-data-source-to.html